# Quickest way to get amazon s3 bucket size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As of now i am calculating the size of an amazon s3 bucket by iterating over all the objects and adding up the size of individual objects.
This is quite time consuming.
I tried parallelising the operation and saved some time but even then it takes a lot of time.

System I am using : EC2 m1.large

Is there any workarounds or better means to find out the bucket size?

Note: i dont have access to aws console, just have the access keys

Comment: You could use the API - getBucket - the data returned includes sizes. You will still need to iterate and sum the results, but this may be quicker:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Comment: how is it going to be faster? And it is says it ll return only 1000 objects max.

Comment: You only need one API call per 1000 objects. I said it *may* be quicker - might be worth trying? If you read the link you will see that you can use marker attribute to page data. See Jim Z answer here http://serverfault.com/questions/84815/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket

Comment: There are not a lot of options here. If you do need to do things like this on a regular basis, you may want to keep some extra metadata in an RDMS. That way you can get your answer quickly.

Answer (score 9):

Probably a bit late, but I was looking for this too and found you can get this information already computed from CloudWatch.  From the command line, you can call this to list the S3 buckets you have which have BucketSizeBytes stat available:

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --metric-name BucketSizeBytes
```

This gives a list of things like this:

```
    {
        "Namespace": "AWS/S3", 
        "Dimensions": [
            {
                "Name": "BucketName", 
                "Value": "myReallyGreatBucket"
            }, 
            {
                "Name": "StorageType", 
                "Value": "StandardStorage"
            }
        ], 
        "MetricName": "BucketSizeBytes"
    }
```

So basically the bucket size is partitioned into Standard storage size and Reduced Redundancy storage size byte counts.  You want these separate so you can know how much full price storage you're using and how much of the cheaper storage.  If you want the total bytes for another purpose, just add the two.  To go get them, you can call it to get a variety of computed-over-time counts [AWS CloudWatch get-metric-statistics CLI options](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html).  I got it to work by specifying to get the time for a day:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/S3 --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value=myReallyGreatBucket Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --start-time 2015-08-23T00:00:00 --end-time 2015-08-24T00:00:00 --period 86400 --statistics Average --unit Bytes
{
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2015-08-23T00:00:00Z", 
            "Average": 436306296.0, 
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        }
    ], 
    "Label": "BucketSizeBytes"
}
```

It didn't work when I tried to get the average for a minute or an hour- just returned an empty list.  For a full day, it worked as shown.

You can call this same stuff through the REST API but I haven't tried that yet.  Presumably the same values would work.

Comment: Great idea using the cloudwatch metrics but one gotcha, For some reason BucketSizeBytes only includes the size of standard and reduced redudency storage. Glacer bytes are not included ! If you want bucket sizes including Glacer I still can't find a way to do it without cycling through all the keys.

Comment: @Sam The OP was asking about S3, not Glacier- so I hadn't considered if this worked there or not :-)  Good to know this wouldn't work there though.  I wonder, did you try changing the namespace?  In the command I showed it is "AWS/S3".  Maybe there's a Glacier namespace?  If there is, then you may also have to pass a different dimension and/or metric name.

Comment: Instead of average is it possible to print current bucket size in Terabytes atm?